# Using reserved words as property names in C# classes

Tags: c#

Is there a way for me to use reserved words in C# as property names in my class?

I'm communicating with a third party API and need to have a property named `object` in lowercase letters. Is there a way for me to escape the property name so I can use this reserved word?

So, my class will look like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string object { get; set; }
   public string last_name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Most probably, you don't need a property named `object`. You need a property which will be serialized to a JSON property / XML tag named `object`.

Comment: That's what I thought too but I'm checking it in Fiddler and it's a string property.

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't solve it?

Comment: @JeremyThompson Yes, it did help. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

If using json, so just you need using **attribute** to solve the issue. The property `name` can help you. For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("object")]
    public string Object { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, using Newtonsoft.Json, you can serialize and deserialize the data as what is needed. Moreover, you can do this for other members.

Comment: `[JsonPropertyName("")]` worked on my side, for example  

`[JsonPropertyName("switch")]
public string Switch { get; set; }`