# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject return null

Tags: c#, json

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject return NULL for sample json. How to deal with params keyword. As params not allowed as variable name. How should I define class for ResponseHeader

JSON

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0,
        "params": {
            "q": "name:*",
            "fq": "type:cxx"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 97347,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [
            {
                "id": "923296961",
                "name": [
                    "filename1.cxx"
                ],
                "type": [
                    "cxx"
                ],
                "_version_": 1639732671000084481
            },
            {
                "id": "2943974139",
                "name": [
                    "filename12.cxx"
                ],
                "type": [
                    "cxx"
                ],
                "_version_": 1639732671000084482
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Classes

```
public class Params
    {
        public string q { get; private set; }
        public string fq { get; private set; }
    }
    public class ResponseHeader
    {
        public int status { get; private set; } 
        public int QTime { get; private set; }
        Params ??? { get; private set }
    }

    public class Record
    {
        public int id { get; private set; }
        public string [] name { get; private set; }
        public string [] type { get; private set; }
        public int _version_ { get; private set; }
    }
    public class Response
    {
        public int numFound { get; private set; }
        public int start { get; private set; }
        public Record [] docs { get; private set; }
    }

    public class GetResponse
    {
        public ResponseHeader respHead { get; private set; } 
        public Response resp { get; private set; }
    }
```

Here I am passing above json as input to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject .

```
GetResponse getResp = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetResponse>(responseString);
```

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject shoud not return NULL

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47825869/5947043 might help you here

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/ may be useful in future.

Comment: ... the same, but click on [Generate with QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/). You'll see that your classes have more than one problem. Use a `[JsonProperty()]` to rename properties, when their names conflict with the language keywords, for example. Or because you say so.

Answer (score 2):

You are deserializing into the `GetResponse` type, which has two properties called `respHead` and `resp`.

But your JSON string is an object with two properties called `responseHeader` and `response`. The names in the JSON don't match the class.

This should not give you a `null` object. But you will get a `GetResponse` object where `respHead` and `resp` are both null.

If you want it to throw an error if properties are not present, you can use the [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyRequired.htm) attribute on the properties, like this:

```
public class GetResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public ResponseHeader respHead { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public Response resp { get; set; }
}
```

About your `Params` property, you can just use uppercase as the first character. Deserialization is case-insensitive by default, so lower case `params` in the JSON will deserialize to a property called `Params`.

```
public Params Params { get; set; }
```

You also need to remove all instances of `private set;` and use just `set;`. If you use `private`, then only the class itself can set the value, and `JsonConvert` can't.

You're also trying to fit number values that are too big for `int` into `int` properties of your `Record` class.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel I updated responseHeader and response
   

 public class GetResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        public responseHeader1 responseHeader { get; private set; }

        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        public response1 response { get; private set; }
    }

Now I am getting getResp with non null responseHeader and response but response  docs and responseHeader params are NULL

Comment: @PravinHolkar I just updated my answer again, since I was testing your code myself. There are other issues. See my update.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel It worked. This is my first C# with json example.